# How can I access neo4j running on my local Mac from server

Tags: php, mysql, neo4j, cpanel, remote-server

I have neo4j running on my localhost port 7474 on MAC and I would like to access the same from server http://www.example.com/test/

How can I do that? I tried adding IP on remote mysql in cpanel on server and its not working. Is there any other setting I should do/add on MAC ?

php code:

```
<?php

    // connect
    $cs = mysql_connect ( '123.123.123.123:7474', '', '' ) or die ( 'Can not connect to server' );

?>
```

error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.123.123.123' on line 4
```

also:

```
   $link = mysqli_connect("123.123.123.123:7474","","","") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Error:

```
Unknown MySQL server host 
 mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given
```

Answer (score 1):

neo4j is not mysql, and cannot be accessed through a mysql driver.

Visit this URL for more information on accessing neo4j from PHP:
http://neo4j.com/developer/php/

You can test access using the neo4j-shell as well, if you have SSH access to your remote server:
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-starting.html

Also, if you want to access neo4j running on your local Mac from a server hosted in some datacenter somewhere, you'll need to make sure you can route the traffic to your local Mac.  It seems like you've figured out how to do that (based on the MySQL errors).

For the reference of others, you'll need to adjust conf/neo4j-server.properties to reference 'org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0'.  This will make sure that neo4j binds to all IP addresses on the local box and not just 127.0.0.1.  Additionally, if your Mac is behind NAT (network address translation), then your IP address will not be directly Internet-accessible (ie, if it's something like 192.168.1.12).  In this case, you'll want to do port mapping on your router to map your real IP address:7474 to 192.168.1.12:7474, and then connect to your real IP address:7474 when accessing from an external server.

Comment: How can I make my local mac ip accessible then?ANy tutorial or start would be greatly appreciated.Thanks for the brief .Yes and the ip is something like 192.168........ .What should be my approach ?

Comment: it's going to be on a per-router basis. what's the brand/model of your router?

the typical way to do it is login from your local network to either http://192.168.1.1 or https://192.168.1.1.  default passwords vary, but try 'admin/admin' or 'admin/password'. Then look for port mapping.  You'll want to map port 7474 on your external network to your local IP address.  That'll work for a while. However, since the local address is likely issued via DHCP from your router on a "lease," you'll also want to tell the router to always issue the same one to your computer (called static/reserved  DHCP).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot pass `$link` as argument for `mysqli_error` because it's not defined yet

`$link = mysqli_connect(...) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`

proper way is e.g:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
if ($link->connect_errno) {
    die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

**I don't know if neo4j is running as MySQL server, than probably you need other database driver for PHP**

Comment: is `neo4j` mysql server?

Comment: no I guess.But basically I just want access the ip path of the localhost .Is it possible??